# Can you activate more than 2 magic rings in one turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, action-economy

The idea stems from one of my players but can you tie magic rings (enchanted with magic missile) together and activate them all in one action? So for example they have ten magic rings all with the same spell, can he use all the rings as they are tied together (essentially creating a single object.)

Comment: Related: "[Can a creature activate multiple items at once with the same command word?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178829)" and perhaps: "[Does the Pole of Angling's command word require an action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151435)" (an item with no action-economy cost to being activated)

Comment: While the duplicate gives a good answer, I am not sure it is an actual duplicate, because this question is hinting at 'can you tie magic items together and combine effects' more than just asking about command words. That said the OP will hopefully come back to clarify.